# Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{\sqrt[nr]{x_i^{nr}+(n^{nr}-1)\prod_{j=1}^nx^r_j}} \ge 1$ for all $x_i>0$ and $r \geq \frac{1}{n}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, summation, conjectures

> Prove that, for all $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n>0$ and $r \geq \frac{1}{n}$, it holds that
> $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{\sqrt[nr]{x_i^{nr}+(n^{nr}-1)\prod \limits_{j=1}^nx^r_j}} \ge 1.$$

This is a slightly modified version of my earlier question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370084/) (which corresponds to the case $r=1$).

The case $n=3$ and $r=\frac{2}{3}$ can be reduced to the inequality problem of IMO 2001 ([Problem 2](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2001_IMO_Problems/Problem_2)).

The case $r=\frac{1}{n}$ can be reduced to
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i^{n-1}}{x_i^{n-1}+(n-1) \prod_{j\neq i}x_j}\geq \sum_{i=1}^n\,\frac{x_i^{n-1}}{x_i^{n-1}+\sum_{j\neq i}\,x_j^{n-1}}=1\,.$$
(Note that we have an equality case when $n=2$ and $r=\frac1n$ here, regardless of the values of the variables $x_i$.)

Comment: The claim is untrue. Take $n=2,x_1=1,x_2=2$ and $r\in(0,0.5)$.

Comment: Seems to work if $r\ge 1$. I've not proven it yet though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For Bounty Hunters:**  ***This is "the current answer" I referred to in my bounty message.  (I added this remark, so that people know which answer I meant if there are other answers.)  The proof is cumbersome.  I am very dissatisfied with it.  I seek improvement.***

Here is a proof of the OP's ineq for $r=\frac{k}{n}$ when $k$ is a positive integer. The proof the OP's conjecture for an arbitrary value $r\ge \frac1n$ is given later.  I will show that for all positive integers $n$ and $k$, and for any real numbers $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n>0$, we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{\sqrt[k]{x_i^k+(n^k-1)\prod_{j=1}^nx_j^{\frac{k}{n}}}}\ge1,\tag{0}$$ establishing the OP's conjecture for $r=\frac{k}{n}$.  The proof is contingent upon the inequalities
$$\frac{x_i}{\sqrt[k]{x_i^k+(n^k-1)\prod_{j=1}^nx_j^{\frac{k}{n}}}}\ge \frac{x_i^{1-\frac1{n^k}}}{\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^{1-\frac1{n^k}}}\tag{1}$$
for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.  The equality cases of $(0)$ and $(1)$ are the same:

- $(n,k)=(2,1)$, and
- $x_1=x_2=\ldots=x_n$.

To verify $(1)$, we assume wlog that $i=n$.  We prove the equivalent inequality
$$\left(1+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}y_j^{1-\frac1{n^k}}\right)^k-1 \ge (n^k-1)\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}y_j^{\frac{k}{n}},\tag{2}$$
where $y_j=\frac{x_j}{x_n}$ for $j=1,2,\ldots,n-1$.  There are five equality cases for $(2)$ if we allow $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_{n-1}$ to be non-negative real numbers:

- $n=1$,
- $(n,k)=(2,1)$,
- $y_1=y_2=\ldots=y_{n-1}=0$,
- $y_1=y_2=\ldots=y_{n-1}=1$, and
- $k=1$ with $y_1=y_2=\ldots=y_{n-1}$.

The lhs of $(2)$ is a sum of $(n^k-1)$ terms of the form
$$Y_{(t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_{k})}=\prod_{\substack{1\le r\le k\\ t_r\ne n}} y_{t_r}^{1-\frac{1}{n^k}}$$
where $t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_{k}$ are positive integers not greater than $n$ s.t. not all of them are $n$.  Write $t=(t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_k)$, and $T$ for the set of all possible tuples $t$.

Note that $|T|=n^k-1$.  By AM-GM
$$\left(1+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}y_j^{1-\frac1{n^k}}\right)^k-1=\sum_{t\in T}Y_t\ge |T|\left(\prod_{t\in T}Y_t\right)^{1/|T|}=(n^k-1)\left(\prod_{t\in T} Y_t\right)^{\frac{1}{n^k-1}}.$$
Hence if we can show that
$$\prod_{t\in T} Y_t=\left(\prod_{j=1}^{n-1} y_j^{\frac{k}{n}}\right)^{n^k-1},\tag{3}$$
then $(2)$ follows immediately.  However by setting $y_n=1$, we have
$$\prod_{t\in T}Y_t=\prod_{t_1=1}^n\prod_{t_2=1}^n\ldots\prod_{t_{k}=1}^n\prod_{r=1}^k y_{t_r}^{1-\frac1{n^k}}.\tag{4}$$

For $i=1,2,\ldots,n-1$, $y_i^{1-\frac{1}{n^k}}$ appears in the product in the rhs of $(4)$ in total \begin{align}\sum_{s=0}^k s\binom{k}{s}(n-1)^{k-s}&=k\sum_{s=1}^{k-1}\binom{k-1}{s-1}(n-1)^{(k-1)-(s-1)}\\&=k\big(1+(n-1)\big)^{k-1}=kn^{k-1}\end{align}
times.  This means
$$\prod_{t\in T}Y_t=\prod_{i=1}^n \left(y_i^{1-\frac{1}{n^k}}\right)^{kn^{k-1}}=\prod_{i=1}^n\left( y_i^{\frac{k}{n}}\right)^{n^k-1}.$$  This justifies $(3)$ and we are done.

---

Here is a proof of the OP's ineq for any real value $r\ge \frac1n$.  We want to show that $(2)$ is true for any real number $k\ge 1$ and for any real numbers $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_{n-1}\ge 0$.  Furthermore when $0<k<1$ and $n>1$, it is not difficult to see that that there are always counterexamples of $(2)$.  Hence, when $k>0$ and $n>1$, the inequalities $(0)$ and $(1)$ always hold for any positive reals $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ if and only if $k\ge 1$; the ineq $(2)$ always hold for any non-negative reals $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_{n-1}$ iff $k\ge 1$.  This means: for $r>0$ and $n>1$, the OP's inequality holds for any positive reals $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ if and only if $r\ge \frac1n$.

Rewrite $(2)$ in the following form:
$$\left(1+\sum_{j=1}^m z_j\right)^k -1 \ge \big((1+m)^k-1\big)\prod_{j=1}^m z_j^{\frac{k (1+m)^{k-1}}{(1+m)^k-1}},$$
where $z_j=y_j^{1-\frac{1}{n^k}}$ and $m=n-1$.  By setting $z_j=\frac{w_j}{m}$ where $w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_m\ge 0$, we get yet another form of $(2)$.  Let $A_m$ and $G_m$ denote the arithmetic mean and the geometric mean of $w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_m$.  Then we need to prove
$$(1+A_m)^k-1\geq \frac{(1+m)^k-1}{m^{\frac{km(1+m)^{k-1}}{(1+m)^k-1}}}G_m^{\frac{km(1+m)^{k-1}}{(1+m)^k-1}}$$
for all real numbers $k\ge 1$.  Since $A_m\ge G_m$, it suffices to show that$$(1+G_m)^k-1\geq \frac{(1+m)^k-1}{m^{\frac{km(1+m)^{k-1}}{(1+m)^k-1}}}G_m^{\frac{km(1+m)^{k-1}}{(1+m)^k-1}}$$
for all real numbers $k\ge 1$.  More generally, we want to prove
$$\frac{(1+g)^k-1}{(1+\mu)^k-1} \geq \left(\frac{g}{\mu}\right)^{\frac{k\mu(1+\mu)^{k-1}}{(1+\mu)^k-1}}\tag{5}$$
for all real numbers $g$, $\mu$, and $k$ such that $g\ge 0$, $\mu> 0$, and $k\ge 1$ (with equality cases $g=0$, $g=\mu$, and $k=1$).  We will also see that $(5)$ is reversed when $0<k<1$ and $k<0$ (in both ranges, the equality conditions are $g=0$ and $g=\mu$).

Let
$$F(g)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
(1+g)^k(1+\mu)^k-\mu g\left(\frac{(1+g)^k-(1+\mu)^k}{g-\mu}\right)-\frac{g(1+g)^k-\mu(1+\mu)^k}{g-\mu} &\text{if }g\ne \mu,\\
(1+\mu)^{2k}-(1+\mu)^{k}(1+k\mu) & \text{if }g=\mu.\end{array}\right.$$
Then
$$H'(g)=\frac{k (g-\mu) F(g)}{g^{\frac{k\mu(1+\mu)^{k-1}}{(1+\mu)^k-1}+1}\big((1+\mu)^k-1\big)(1+\mu)(1+g)},$$
if
$$H(g)=\frac{(1+g)^k-1}{g^{\frac{k\mu(1+\mu)^{k-1}}{(1+\mu)^k-1}}}.$$
If we can show that when $k>1$, $F(g)>0$ for all $g>0$, then it follows that $H(g)$ achieves the minimum value at $g=\mu$, proving $(5)$.  Anyway, $F(g)>0$ for all $g>0$ if and only if
$$(1+g)^{k-1}(1+\mu)^{k-1}\ge \frac{g(1+g)^{k-1}-\mu(1+\mu)^{k-1}}{g-\mu}\tag{6}$$
for all $g\ne \mu$ and $k\ge 1$ (with equality case $k=1$).  To prove $(6)$, it suffices to assume that $g>\mu\ge 0$.

In fact, we will prove that $(6)$ is true for all positive reals $g,\mu$ s.t. $g\ne \mu$ and for any $k\in(-\infty,0]\cup [1,\infty)$ with equality cases $k=0$ and $k=1$.  Moreover $(6)$ is reversed when $k\in(0,1)$ without equality cases.  The reversed inequality of $(6)$ when $0<k<1$ is significant because it allows us to find counterexamples of $(0)$, $(1)$, and $(2)$ when $n>1$ and $0<k<1$.

If $\kappa=k-1$, then $(6)$ is equivalent to
$$(1+g)^{\kappa}\frac{(1+\mu)^{\kappa}-1}{\mu}\ge \frac{(1+g)^{\kappa}-(1+\mu)^{\kappa}}{g-\mu}\tag{7}$$
for all $g>\mu>0$ and $\kappa \ge 0$ and $\kappa\le -1$ (with equality cases $\kappa=0$ and $\kappa=-1$).  We have a reversed version of $(7)$ for $-1<\kappa<0$ (without equality cases).   Once $(7)$ is established, $(5)$ and $(6)$ follow immediately.  Hence $(0)$, $(1)$, and $(2)$ are true for all real numbers $k\ge 1$.

---

Now we prove $(7)$ for $\kappa\ge 0$ and $\kappa<-1$, as well as its reversed version for $-1\le \kappa<0$.  The main idea is Bernoulli's ineq:
$$(1+x)^{\alpha}\ge 1+\alpha x$$
for all $x>-1$ and $\alpha\in (-\infty,0]\cup[1,\infty)$ (with equality cases $x=0$, $\alpha=0$, and $\alpha=1$).  The inequality above is reversed for $0<\alpha<1$ (with $x=0$ as the sole equality condition). We assume $g>\mu>0$ throughout.

If $\kappa \ge 1$, then by Bernoulli's ineq
$$\frac{(1+\mu)^\kappa-1}\mu\ge \kappa$$
and
$$\frac{1-\left(\frac{1+\mu}{1+g}\right)^\kappa}{g-\mu}=\frac{1-\left(1-\frac{g-\mu}{1+g}\right)^\kappa}{g-\mu}\le \frac{\kappa}{1+g}.$$
Thus
$$\frac{(1+\mu)^\kappa-1}\mu\ge \kappa\ge\frac{\kappa}{1+g}\ge\frac{1-\left(\frac{1+\mu}{1+g}\right)^\kappa}{g-\mu}$$
proving $(7)$.  For $\kappa\ge 1$, $(7)$ is a strict ineq.

If $0\le \kappa<1$, then Bernoulli's ineq implies
$$\frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{1+\mu}\right)^\kappa}{\mu}=\frac{1-\left(1-\frac{\mu}{1+\mu}\right)^\kappa}{\mu}\ge \frac{\kappa}{1+\mu}$$
and
$$\frac{\left(\frac{1+g}{1+\mu}\right)^\kappa-1}{g-\mu}=\frac{\left(1+\frac{g-\mu}{1+\mu}\right)^\kappa-1}{g-\mu}\le \frac{\kappa}{1+\mu}.$$
Hence
$$(1+g)^\kappa\frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{1+\mu}\right)^\kappa}{\mu}\ge \frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{1+\mu}\right)^\kappa}{\mu} \ge  \frac{\kappa}{1+\mu}\ge \frac{\left(\frac{1+g}{1+\mu}\right)^\kappa-1}{g-\mu}$$
proving $(7)$. For $0<\kappa<1$, $(7)$ is a strict ineq.

We also show that the inequality $(7)$ is flipped when $-1\le\kappa<0$.  For $-1\le \kappa<0$, Bernoulli's ineq implies
$$\frac{\left(\frac{1}{1+\mu}\right)^{-\kappa}-1}{\mu}=\frac{\left(1-\frac{\mu}{1+\mu}\right)^{-\kappa}-1}{\mu}\le\frac{\kappa}{1+\mu}$$
and
$$\frac{1-\left(\frac{1+g}{1+\mu}\right)^{-\kappa}}{g-\mu}=\frac{1-\left(1+\frac{g-\mu}{1+\mu}\right)^{-\kappa}}{g-\mu}\ge\frac{\kappa}{1+\mu}.$$
Thus
$$\frac{\left(\frac{1}{1+\mu}\right)^{-\kappa}-1}{\mu}\le\frac{\kappa}{1+\mu}\le\frac{1-\left(\frac{1+g}{1+\mu}\right)^{-\kappa}}{g-\mu}$$
reversing $(7)$.  The reversed version of $(7)$ is strict for $-1<\kappa<0$.

Lastly we want to prove that for $\kappa<-1$, $(7)$ holds once again.  Using Bernoulli's ineq, we get
$$\frac{\left(\frac{1}{1+\mu}\right)^{-\kappa}-1}{\mu}=\frac{\left(1-\frac{\mu}{1+\mu}\right)^{-\kappa}-1}{\mu}\ge\frac{\kappa}{1+\mu}$$
and
$$\frac{1-\left(\frac{1+g}{1+\mu}\right)^{-\kappa}}{g-\mu}=\frac{1-\left(1+\frac{g-\mu}{1+\mu}\right)^{-\kappa}}{g-\mu}\le\frac{\kappa}{1+\mu}.$$
Thus
$$\frac{\left(\frac{1}{1+\mu}\right)^{-\kappa}-1}{\mu}\ge\frac{\kappa}{1+\mu}\ge\frac{1-\left(\frac{1+g}{1+\mu}\right)^{-\kappa}}{g-\mu}$$
establishing $(7)$.  The ineq $(7)$ is strict for $\kappa<-1$.

---

From the result above, we can also show that
$$\left(1+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}y_j^{\frac{n}{n-1}\left(1-\frac1{n^k}\right)}\right)^k-1\ge (n^k-1)\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}y_j^{\frac{k}{n-1}}$$
for every integer $n>1$, for any real number $k\ge 1$, and for all real numbers $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_{n-1}\ge 0$ with two equality cases: $(n,k)=(2,1)$ and $y_1=y_2=\ldots=y_{n-1}\in\{0,1\}$.  This implies
$$\frac{x_i}{\sqrt[k]{x_i^k+(n^k-1)\prod_{j\ne i}x_j^{\frac{k}{n-1}}}}\ge \frac{x_i^{\frac{n}{n-1}\left(1-\frac1{n^k}\right)}}{\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^{\frac{n}{n-1}\left(1-\frac1{n^k}\right)}}$$
and
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{\sqrt[k]{x_i^k+(n^k-1)\prod_{j\ne i}x_j^{\frac{k}{n-1}}}}\ge 1$$
for every integer $n>1$, for any real number $k\ge 1$, and for all real numbers $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n}> 0$.  The equality conditions of the last two inequalities are $(n,k)=(2,1)$ or $x_1=x_2=\ldots=x_n$.  The [second problem of IMO 2001](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2001_IMO_Problems/Problem_2) is a special case of the last inequality, where $(n,k)=(3,2)$.

Comment: Thanks for you efforts!

Answer (score 2):

The following reasoning can give a solution.

Let $nr=\alpha$.

Thus, $\alpha\geq1$ and we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{\left(x_i^{\alpha}+(n^{\alpha}-1)\prod\limits_{j=1}^nx_j^{\frac{\alpha}{n}}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}\geq1.$$
Now, by Holder $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{\left(x_i^{\alpha}+(n^{\alpha}-1)\prod\limits_{j=1}^nx_j^{\frac{\alpha}{n}}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}\right)^{\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\left(x_i^{\alpha}+(n^{\alpha}-1)\prod\limits_{j=1}^nx_j^{\frac{\alpha}{n}}\right)\geq\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^{\alpha+1}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^{\alpha+1}\geq\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{\alpha+1}+(n^{\alpha}-1)\prod\limits_{j=1}^nx_j^{\frac{\alpha}{n}}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i,$$
which is true by Muirhead for any integer $\alpha\geq n$.

Now, let $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i$ be a constant and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i^{\alpha+1}$ be a constant.

Thus, by the Vasc's EV Method (https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/059_06_JIPAM/059_06.pdf Corollary 1.8 b )

$\prod\limits_{j=1}^nx_j$ gets a maximal value for equality case of $n-1$ variables.

Since the last inequality is homogeneous, it's enough to assume $x_2=...=x_n=1$ and $x_1=x$,

which gives something easier.

Comment: Not sure if you noticed this thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3769559/maximum-of-sum-cycx-1x-2x-3-cdots-x-k-given-x-1x-2-ldotsx-n-a-for-non.  Do you know the answers to all cases?  And thanks for this answer.

Comment: @Batominovsk Thank you! I did not see it.